# How to express "but" using quantifiers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers, word-problem

We were asked to express some functions using quantifiers then find the negation of the statement, so that no negation is left of a quantifier then express it in simple english.

we were given this statement:
**"Everyone is rich, but unhappy"**
and i'm not sure how to express it
i thought of these:

∀x(R(x) ∧ F(x))
or
∀x(R(x) → F(x))

Comment: A "but" is really an "and."

Comment: but can we use "and" with ∀x. my friend told me we can't use it for some reason :/

Comment: It sound a little bit weird that "but" means "and", but consider "he is rich but not happy"; it means: "he is rich and not happy".

Comment: Yes, but... we have to consider the difference between: "if a human is rich, than he is unhappy" and "every human is rich and unhappy". Do we agree that the two statements "sound different" ?

Comment: The first one is correctly symbolized with: $\forall x (Rich(x) \to Unhappy(x))$, that is true also if there are not rich men at all.

Comment: If we write $\forall x (Rich(x) \land Unhappy(x))$ we assert also that everyone is rich.

Comment: Logically "and" and "but are the same.  The only difference in "natural language" is purely emotional.  I think you misunderstood what your friend meant when s/he said you can't use "and" with all.

Comment: I'm not sure what your friend meant.  If s/he had said you can't use "and" with "there exist" or "or" with "all", I'd think that was a misstatement of $\forall x(A(x) \lor B(x)) \ne \forall x(A(x)) \lor \forall x(B(x))$ and $\exists x(A(x) \land B(x) \ne \exists x(A(x)) \land \exists x(B(x))$.

Comment: @fleablood It's hard for me to tell how literal you're being. "But" isn't emotional. "But" is a conjunction, just like "and", but they are very different. In my native language, "but" is classified as an "adversative conjunction". It just so happens that predicate calculus' conjunction "$\land$" isn't strong enough to model the natural language's "but", and that's OK in practice, predicate calculus is powerful enough as it is.

Comment: I don't know what "adversative conjunction" means.  (I'll look it up).  But what *logical* difference can "but" have from "and".  I am poor, but happy means I am both poor and happy and there is an implication that although being poor would be a bad thing, being happy is a good thing.  But that implication is not stated and is not part of the logical evaluative aspect of the sentence.   You say "but" and "and" are "very different".  Why?  What actually is the difference and would that difference be expressible in math logic?

Comment: Okay, "adversative" implies contrast is being drawn attention to.  That's very real and is what I meant by "emotional"  being rich is a good thing but being unhappy is a bad thing in contrast.  In math the contrast need not be stated.  Or if it is stated it would be stated on its own.  The math equivalent would be.  "I am rich and I am unhappy; richness is good; unhappy is bad" (ergo "all things that I am are not of equal worth").  I'm going to stand on my statement that *logically* "and" and "but" are equivalent and that the contrast is "emotional" and not relevant.

Comment: @fleablood "Math logic" is a very broad term. There is no difference in predicate calculus between "but" and "and", but that's a limitation of predicate calculus. There are other kinds of calculi (see for instance [modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic) in which one can model stuff such as "I might be hungry", which is something you can't do in predicate calculus), there might be one in which one can properly model "but". And even if there isn't, it is possible that it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can reword the sentence as "Everyone is unhappy, but rich." Unlike implication, conjunction is a commutative operator.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $F(x)$ stands for '$x$ is unhappy', you should use

$$\forall x (R(x) \land F(x))$$
 because saying that 'everyone is rich but unhappy' is ssaying that everyone is rich and unhappy.

You were told that "the $\land$ doesn;t go with the $\forall$", because *often* you indeed want to use the $\rightarrow$ with the $\forall$. For example, if we want to say that 'Everyone who is rich is unhappy', we would use $$\forall x (R(x) \rightarrow F(x))$$

Notice that this statement is syaing that everyone who is rich is indeed unhappy, but it does not say that everyone *is* rich. Indeed, while those who are rich are unhappy, this statement says nothing about those are not rich, because the conditional is trivially true for anyone who is not rich.