# is this statement True? False? or not a proposition?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers, word-problem

this is the question i'm working on:

> > Given that U1, U2, U3 are domains for m, n and o respectively, determine weather the following statements are true, false, or not propostion.
> >     U1: {2,6}
> >     U2:{-2,3,10}
> >     U3:{5}
> >     l(m,n): m ≤ n
> >     s(m,n,o): m+n=o
> >     e(m): m is even
> >     the statements:
> >     A)∀m ∃n ( e(m) ∧ l(m,n) )
> >     B)∀m ∀n ∃o s(m,n,o)
> >     C)∀o ∃m ∃n s(m,n,o)

my answers were:
A)not proposition
B)False
C)True
but I'm still not sure could someone help me?

Comment: Can you explain your answers?  In logic (and math in general), we really don't care about your answers, but about how you got to them.

Comment: To start, explain why A) is not a proposition.

Comment: for A it was True at first but when i found out that there is a third option (not proposition) i choose it because somewhere in the slides it says we can't use ∀ with ∧ so i changed it

Comment: I've never heard of a rule saying that "we can't use $\forall$ with $\land$". There's definitely no rule against using $\forall$ and $\land$ in the same statement.

Comment: @Mon  Agh!  That's the second time you're foiled by the "You can't use a $\land$ with a $\forall$" ... that is just not true: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455962/how-to-express-but-using-quantifiers

Comment: for B i tried each number in U1 and U2 and i understood that all the numbers when we try it here m+n = o.  thats why it's false, and the opposite with C (there should be at least one statement true) and there is a 2+3= 5

Comment: @TannerSwett  i'll make sure to ask my teacher about that point in the slide, sorry.

Comment: @Bram28 i'll make sure to ask my teacher about that point in the slide, sorry.

Comment: @Mon  Don't be sorry!  My "Agh!" was directed not at you, but at whoever made that slide that made you believe you can't use a $\land$ with a $\forall$. :)

Comment: @Mon Your reasoning for your answers for B and C look fine, though for B you may want to point to a specific counterexample, i.e. for which $m$ and $n$ is there no such $o$?

Comment: @Bram28 yeah i did add a counter example in my answer, thank you :D!

Comment: @Bram28 one last thing, if a statement doesn't point the n, like this statement: ∃m l(m,n). This statement is not a proposition right? because they didn't add ∃n or ∀n.

Comment: @Mon That's correct!  All variables need to be quantified for it to be a proposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ is $True$; because all elements of $U_1$ are even and for every element in $U_1$ there exists at least one element in $U_2$ that's larger or equal to the corresponding element in $U_1$.

$B$ is $False$; because we need to find that for every element in $U_1$ and $ U_2$ we can take combinations of elements and sum them to $5$ (elements in $U_3$). A counterexample to prove that it's false, is that $6$ from $U_1$ can't be summed with $-2$ or $3$ or $10$ to get $5.$

$C$ is $True$; because we need to find one element from $U_1$ and $U_2$ each that sums to the elements in $U_3$, which is $5$. So we have $2 + 3 = 5$, which works.